# PHP json_decode casting a problematic value to string instead of float?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have an array of JSON data that i'd like to import. An example of what i'd call non-problematic JSON data would be:

```
[{
  "records": [{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1011546
  },{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1075864
  },{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1132356
  }]
}]
```

The problem that I am having though is that sometimes the data might be like this:

```
[{
  "records": [{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1011546e3
  },{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1075864e3
  },{
    "timestamp": 1437805800,
    "Import": 1132356e3
  }]
}]
```

Where 101546e3 = 101546x10^3 and this is where I am having issues as the default behavior of json_decode because it will cast these values to float and within that, it converts `e3` as 000, or `e5` as 00000 so for the first values above I would get back 1011546000, 1075864000, 1132356000. I can't tell that this value had been modified as it may be a valid value.

How am I able to retrieve the correct value (present within the JSON string before running it through json_decode) from this JSON data given that it may contain the string `e` within what should be an integer value?

Comment: So let me get this straight... you're getting `101546e3` as a numeric field in your JSON and you want to import it as a string. So what you want is a PHP string value that looks like `"101546e3"`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Simba exactly correct. It comes in the JSON without quotes and in doing so json_decode parses it as a float which causes some unwanted behavior for me.

Comment: @RyanVincent Trying to put this simply, I can have 1011546, and 1055632e3 as example numbers. json_decode, somewhere along the line renders "e3" in an encapsulated value as 3 zeros and this is what I mean by being modified. It's not me making the zero's it is json_decode doing it so I can't tell if it's a valid value or not if I run the string through json_decode, only if I inspect the raw string.

Comment: @Simba So essentially, json_decode has the optional parameter JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK which forces float values? I am looking to force string values here.

Comment: Okay, then there's an easy short answer: No you can't. Just to be clear, the JSON string you've quoted contains a numeric value. It is a number. It is not a string. It can only seen as a string if it is enclosed with quote marks in the JSON string. You cannot force this value to be a string unless you modify the incoming JSON itself.

Comment: Simba Thanks for the clarity, I guess i'm just not very good when it comes to math because I realise now that all it is doing is converting the short hand representation into it's full numeric value.

Comment: So if I want to keep the numbers as floating point and as @RyanVincent said, I simply need to convert them back to this format. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` as second parameter in `json_encode()` function

For example

```
$numbers = array('+123123', '-123123', '1.2e3', '0.00001');
var_dump(
 $numbers,
 json_encode($numbers, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
);
echo "Strings containing improperly formatted numbers".PHP_EOL;
$strings = array('+a33123456789', 'a123');
```

Refer [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for second parameter various option

Comment: It returns 1.0e-5 for last parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the input on this as I did not know about this parameter. That being said, you have tested this by explicitly stating that all values in the numbers array are strings however in my example the values are not string values but integers so are not encapsulated by quotes. I have no control over the source so am battling to figure out how to deal with the data unless it's manually parsing the string and thinking up a way to encapsulate these values.